# Builder C++ : import large data to my databse MySql

Tags: mysql, c++builder, dbexpress

i have a problem when import large data to my database Mysql.. 
When i start the insert into datababase is not slow.. after insert a large data (row~40000), the process insert become very slow..

How to enhance the insert process?
Thx

Comment: We can't help, if we don't see your code, how you're inserting.

Comment: Usually, at least with some other databases, englobing your inserts in a transaction helps. Say, create a transaction for every 500 records or so. How many records you want to insert in total?